# Getting data from controller to view without render in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new in nodeJs.I am trying to access the data from Nodejs controller to EJS view without using render(). Because I don't want html to get rendered on client. I just want to process it. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to process all your data inside javascript only and pass to the view only what is needed for rendering. Can help you more if you share some code snippets

Comment: Can you post some snippet of your code and what you want to achieve. I thing you can use ajax to solve this problem if you don't want to re-render your whole page while processing your data, but still you can post your code to better understanding.